# Get GeoLocation of a user in a HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, geolocation

How can I get the location of the user who view my HTTPS (Secure) site in Javascript?

Or is there's any free HTTPS-based API web services that I can use?

It disables my javascript to get my location

Comment: what disables your javascript ?  this is quite easy but the user has to submit retrieving the data   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Yes, but the link that you give and other way to get geolocation is a HTTP-based API only.

Comment: Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642796/getting-users-geolocation-via-html5-and-javascript